# ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I Get this Error after the completion of compiler.I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the firebase @angular/fire but can't get it fixed . I am confused about the error.I can't find it's solution

```
"@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
"firebase": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.3",
```

```js
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'analytics'. Did you mean to use 'import analytics from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:21 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'app'. Did you mean to use 'import app from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                      ~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:26 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'auth'. Did you mean to use 'import
auth from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                           ~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:32 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'database'. Did you mean to use 'import database from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                 ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:42 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';

node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/document/document.d.ts:5:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

5 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/collection-group/collection-group.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:8:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use
'import firestore from "../../../firebase"' instead?

8 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
```

Comment: To start, can you clarify what you mean by the completion of the compiler?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This incompatibility issue has been flagged on the official `@angular/fire` GitHub page [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2619#issue-730431158)

The proposed workaround worked for me. In short:

1. Uninstall your current `@angular/fire` package (`npm uninstall @angular/fire`)
2. Install the latest version in development instead (`6.0.4-canary.9a26fbe`) with `npm i @angular/fire@6.0.4-canary.9a26fbe --save`, as per instructions from the Maintainer [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2619#issuecomment-719141243)
3. Once version `6.0.4` will be out (not yet as of today), we can switch back to the latest official release. Meanwhile this should keep you going.

Comment: Did not work for me, I had to downgrade firebase

Answer (score 11):

Use this command

```
npm i firebase@7.24.0 angularfire2 --save
```

Answer (score 4):

Do the following steps:

1. `npm uninstall @angular/fire`
2. `npm install @angular/fire@latest`

Also
in your `environment.ts` only add below properties, avoid adding `appId` and `measurementId` (as it's there in firebase but you don't need it).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are following the version compatibility chart here

https://github.com/angular/angularfire#angular-and-firebase-versions

Comment: This was helpful.  Even though I thought I was installing the latest firebase, I was actually still on v6 and my Angular version was 11 which are incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

to compilerOptions in tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your firebase version. I had the same problem trying to use it and I downgraded it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).