# Angular firestore configuration

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an Agular App using firestore. I have done what I think I should do but I keep having this error.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'analytics'. Did you mean to use 'import analytics from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:21 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'app'. Did you mean to use 'import app from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                      ~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:26 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'auth'. 
Did you mean to use 'import auth from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                           ~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:32 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'database'. Did you mean to use 'import database from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                 ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:42 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:53 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'functions'. Did you mean to use 'import functions from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:64 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'messaging'. Did you mean to use 'import messaging from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:75 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'performance'. Did you mean to use 'import performance from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:88 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'remoteConfig'. Did you mean to use 'import remoteConfig from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:102 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'storage'. Did you mean to use 'import storage from "../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                                                       ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/document/document.d.ts:5:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

5 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/collection-group/collection-group.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:8:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../firebase"' instead?

8 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
           ~~~~~~~~~
```

I have even uninstalled and re-installed angular CLI, yet the problem persists.

Who can help?

See my code below:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I`m not sure where this is coming from? Could this be from my machine or its a bug from angular and/ or firebase?

Answer (score 3):

I think for now you need to downgrade the firebase package in package.json to "firebase": "^7.23.0". I think you are using "firebase": "8.0.0"

Comment: I downgraded firebase and @angular/fire and it worked. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No problem. You don't need to downgrade @angular/fire, just firebase

Answer (score 0):

There is a valid workaround that does not require a downgrade of firebase.

Please see my separate answer / proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64612430/13714870).