# No exported member error with firebase when trying to compile angular 10 project

Tags: angular, firebase

I installed an angular dashboard template which I tested with ng serve to confirm worked. I then run

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
```

to install firebase. And after adding firebase project credentials and editing the app.module.ts

```
    import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    import { AuthInterceptor, AuthService, FakeBackendInterceptor } from '@services/*';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ChartsModule } from './pages/charts';
    import { ComponentsModule } from './pages/components';
    import { DashboardModule } from './pages/dashboard';
    import { Dashboard2Module } from './pages/dashboard2';
    import { FormsModule } from './pages/forms';

    import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/auth";
    import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        DashboardModule,
        Dashboard2Module,
        FormsModule,
        ChartsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule, 
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: AuthInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: FakeBackendInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

I get the following errors when I try to compile.

```
    ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'analytics'. Did you mean to use 'import analytics from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
               ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:21 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'app'. Did you mean to use 'import app from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                          ~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:26 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'auth'. Did you mean to use 'import auth from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                               ~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:32 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'database'. Did you mean to use 'import database from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                     ~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:42 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                               ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:53 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'functions'. Did you mean to use 'import functions from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:64 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'messaging'. Did you mean to use 'import messaging from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:75 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'performance'. Did you mean to use 'import performance from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:88 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'remoteConfig'. Did you mean to use 'import remoteConfig from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:2:102 - error TS2614: Module '"../../firebase"' has no exported member 'storage'. Did you mean to use 'import storage from "../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { analytics, app, auth, database, firestore, functions, messaging, performance, remoteConfig, storage } from 'firebase/app';
                                                                                                           ~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:4:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'User'. Did you mean to use 'import User from "../../../firebase"' instead?

    4 import { User, auth } from 'firebase/app';
               ~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:4:16 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'auth'. Did you mean to use 'import auth from "../../../firebase"' instead?

    4 import { User, auth } from 'firebase/app';
                     ~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:12:14 - error TS2411: Property 'authState' of type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to string index type 'Promise<any> & ((...args: unknown[]) => Promise<any>) & ((...args: unknown[]) => any)'.

    12     readonly authState: Observable<User | null>;
                    ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:16:14 - error TS2411: Property 'idToken' of type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to string index type 'Promise<any> & ((...args: unknown[]) => Promise<any>) & ((...args: unknown[]) => any)'.

    16     readonly idToken: Observable<string | null>;
                    ~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:20:14 - error TS2411: Property 'user' of type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to string index type 'Promise<any> & ((...args: unknown[]) => Promise<any>) & ((...args: unknown[]) => any)'.

    20     readonly user: Observable<User | null>;
                    ~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:26:14 - error TS2411: Property 'idTokenResult' of type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to string index type 'Promise<any> & ((...args: unknown[]) => Promise<any>) & ((...args: unknown[]) => any)'.

    26     readonly idTokenResult: Observable<auth.IdTokenResult | null>;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
               ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

    2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
               ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/document/document.d.ts:5:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../../firebase"' instead?

    5m import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
               ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/collection-group/collection-group.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../../firebase"' instead?
    2 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
               ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:8:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../firebase"' has no exported member 'firestore'. Did you mean to use 'import firestore from "../../../firebase"' instead?

    8 import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
```

But I cant figure out the cause of the errors. I have tried looking at several online tutorials for integrating firebase with angular but I cant see anything wrong

**UPDATE**

Attempted following the tutorial in https://www.positronx.io/full-angular-7-firebase-authentication-system/ word for word but I am still getting the same type of error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Angular using Ionic, but after saving all the files and compiling again, the problem was gone. Why? I don't know, but in other projects I had similar situations.

Try to change something irrelevant (like adding some spaces between the lines) of each file you have been editing and save them before compiling.

Comment: Hi @Rolo thanks for the response. let me go over it again and try

Comment: Hi @Rolo .... found the issue. I used firebase@7.24.0 to solve the problem. thanks

Comment: This issue has been resolved in angularfire 6.0.4. Just update to the latest version.

Comment: thanks, it's a goog solution. In fact, I used Marc's solution and works fine too (for now)

Answer (score 6):

There is a valid workaround that does not require a downgrade of firebase (from `8.0` to `7.x` as previously proposed).

Please see my separate answer / proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64612430/13714870).

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue.

Was able to solve it by installing firebase@7.24.0

```
npm i firebase@7.24.0
ng serve
```

Hope it will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone new here
Follow angular fire quick start guide
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

Changing

```js
    import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
```

To

```js
    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
```

Worked for me

you can follow documentation for more help
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md

Answer (score 3):

The error is related to the version of firebase. Your firebase is likely greater than version 8.

`peer firebase@"^7.0 || ^8.0" from @angular/fire@6.1.5`

@angular/fire requires firebase to be either at 7.0 or 8.0.

Run `npm uninstall firebase` and then `npm i firebase@8.0`. That worked for me.

Comment: This was great.  I had forgotten to update my firebase after updating Angular / AngularFire and all my other dependencies.  The revisions didn't match and caused the messy errors that the OP had mentioned. Running an ng update firebase fixed the issue.  Never would've thought of it, had this comment not pointed out the problem with revisions.

Comment: @TomL'esperance glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 2):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

This worked for me.